# Drawing dashed closed paths with Metapost

Tags: metapost

Dashed closed paths usually look lame near the beginning of the path.

[image]

```
beginfig(1);
fill fullcircle scaled 300 withcolor white;
draw fullcircle scaled 250 dashed evenly scaled 3;
endfig;
```

To achieve acceptable results one can replace "3" in "scaled 3" by a number close to 3. Finding the correct number by trial and error is annoying and time-consuming especially if the drawing contains several paths.

How to effectively draw flawless dashed closed paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that automatically scales the length of the dash to fit your path.

[image]

I have wrapped this up in `luamplib`, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`, or adapt it for plain MP

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

def with_length(expr a) = dashpattern(on a off a) enddef;

beginfig(1);
    path C; 
    C = fullcircle scaled 250;
    draw C dashed evenly scaled 3 withcolor red;
    draw C shifted 300 right dashed with_length(arclength C / 128);
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- the `evenly` keyword is actually a dash pattern picture defined in `plain.mp` like this: `picture evenly; evenly=dashpattern(on 3 off 3)`
- so when you write `dashed evenly scaled 3`, MP will draw lines with a pattern 9bp on and 9bp off.
- if the length of your path is not an integer multiple of 18 you get a horrible mess at the start and finish, as you discovered.  This is shown in red in the example above.
- to solve this I have defined a simple macro called `with_length` that lets you specify the length of the dash directly.
- and then all we need is to measure the length of the path in `bp` and divide by the number of dashes and gaps we want.
- the primitive command `arclength` gives us the length, and I chose 128, so there are exactly 64 dashes and 64 gaps, all of equal sizes.
- Note that MP divides by powers of two exactly but you might get tiny rounding errors for other values.

Comment: Cheers. Very simple and works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe using the binary number system could help with the rounding error problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some calculation. Here, we first add pattern with 3mm on and 3mm off. Then we calculate approximately the number of dashes that gives, and finally we draw the path with some modified lengths. Could be put into a macro, if needed.

```
\startMPpage[offset=3bp]
path p; p = fullcircle scaled 200;
numeric plen; plen = arclength p;
numeric dashlen; dashlen = 3mm;
    
draw p dashed dashpattern(on dashlen off dashlen) withcolor darkred;

numeric n; n:=plen div dashlen;

if odd(n) : n:=n+1 fi;

dashlen := plen/n;

draw (p xshifted 25) dashed dashpattern(on dashlen off dashlen);
\stopMPpage
```

[image]